# Exporting a default & declaring anon function all in one

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Here's an example of something I want to do and currently throws an error. I'm not sure I understand why, but it's not syntactically correct to export, assign default, and assign a variable on one line. The benefit of having it be an anon function is that i can use the fat arrow `=>` and open up a return value with `(` and `)` instead of opening `{` and `}` to `return` `jsx`.

```
export default let Checkbox = (props) => (
  <div style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
    <input styleName={styles.checkbox} type="checkbox" />
    <span styleName={styles.checkboxStyled}></span>
  </div>
)
```

Is there a way to do this all in one line? Is there a good reason why I can't / why it's not in the spec?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that for named exports if you want, but not for default ones.

Your alternatives are:

- Don't declare a variable. After all, you just want to export a single value:

  ```
  export default (props) => (
      …
  );
  ```
- Declare the variable and export it in two separate declarations:

  ```
  let Checkbox = (props) => (
      …
  );
  export default Checkbox;
  ```

  If you need to bind to the variable because you want to (re)assign to it (as `let` suggests), use

  ```
  export {Checkbox as default};
  ```
- Use a proper function declaration (which binds the local variable as well):

  ```
  export default function Checkbox(props) {
      return …
  }
  ```

  If you don't need that, you can also export an unnamed function declaration.

Comment: In your last example, the trailing `;` is unnecessary.

Comment: @torazaburo: Right, the semicolon rules are getting more and more confusing with all these new statements and declarations. Something like "*Exports are called declarations, but end in a semicolon like a statement, except when they export a class or function declaration*"?

Comment: It does make sense to export something as default and with a name if (1) you also want to use that thing elsewhere in the file in addition to exporting it or (2) you want to give a name to an arrow function.  It's not that different from using export const x where you define a variable AND export it.