# Arrow function syntax in React stateless components

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've recently discovered the joy of stateless components. For instance, this makes me quite happy (and it works):

```
import { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

export default function ClassroomsOverview(props, context) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{context.classrooms.data.length} Classrooms.</p>
      <p>{context.classrooms.members.length} Students</p>
    </div>
  );
}

ClassroomsOverview.contextTypes = {
  classrooms: PropTypes.object
}
```

I would be even happier if I could make the same component work with [E6 arrow function syntax](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions), like so:

```
import { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

const ClassroomsOverview = (props, context) => (
    <div>
      <p>{context.classrooms.data.length} Classrooms.</p>
      <p>{context.classrooms.members.length} Students</p>
    </div>
  );

ClassroomsOverview.contextTypes = {
  classrooms: PropTypes.object
}
```

I've followed [this video](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-building-stateless-function-components-new-in-react-0-14), but I can't get the arrow syntax version to work.

Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: In the second example (the desired) you are not exporting the const function.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I've tried adding `export default` in front of `const` but I get a compiler error.

Comment: The `export default` is an *operator*, taking an expression as argument ([ref](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_importing-and-exporting-in-detail)); so you could use `export default (props, context) => ....;`. Otherwise you can `export const ClassroomsOverview = (props, context) => ....;`, but this is a *named* export, not the default. I agree with Bergi, use the `export default function` syntax.

Comment: Using deconstruction is even cooler! `const ClassroomsOverview = ({classrooms}) => { //doStuff() }`

Comment: I wonder why would you be even happier using the ES6 arrow function syntax? It can't be typing since that uses 1 more character (specifically `const => ` vs `function`). It can't be the `this` semantics since it's a stateless component. Is it just to avoid using a keyword so it doesn't distract from the component name? Perhaps just to use the new shiny tool absolutely everywhere?

Comment: @DavidMason the reason is aesthetic.

Comment: @DavidMason: You catched me :-) , I just wanted the arrow-function whereever possible. But realizing now, that it is NOT appropriate everywhere (i.e. constructor in react-classes and functional components).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the `export` declaration. Add this to your module:

```
export {ClassroomsOverview as default}
```

I would however recommend using the `export default` syntax with the function declaration.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I missed something obvious. However, if I add `export default` before `const` I get a compiler error. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your suggestion. Could you be more explicit please?

Comment: `export default const X = …;` *is* a syntax error. It's not supported. You can do `export default …;` with just the value, but not with a `const` declaration. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34107388/1048572)

Comment: My recommendation was for your first, already working snippet without the arrow function.

Comment: I see, thanks. Out of curiosity, could you explain what's wrong with doing `export {ClassroomsOverview as default}`.

Comment: It's not wrong, but it's a bit odd. `export default` is more concise and declarative, you don't have to repeat the variable name. At least in my opinion. Choose your own style.